# Can I use Google Maps API in china

Tags: android, google-maps

In my company we have developed an android application that uses Google Maps. specifically we use

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

On very short notice this application will be demoed in China to a Chinese company, and I need to know if we need to replace the map API or not.

I have searched the Internet in home of finding a simple Yes or No answer if maps work or not but it's not clear to me.
I went to china and used maps in the summer och 2011, but shortly after it seams that maps was blocked. Then I read news that Google applied for a licence to provide map services in China bot no word if they got them or not.

If i narrow the search down to results from this year some people claim that it works other that it does not.

So are there any stack overflowers out there in China that can give me a conclusive answer?
I really don't have the time to replace the map API if do not have to

Comment: MapView is not Google-maps-api-3 (tag removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google still has no map publishing license in China (at least as my latest info goes) It may well be that in the near future Google's Map services will be blocked.

A lot of Chinese websites, including ours, use Google's JS as well as their Service API's, Among them is Google's geocoding api.
in china, baidu (NASDAQ:BIDU) and sogou [the minor search engine, part of sohu (NASDAQ:SOHU)] both provided online maps and also APIs,

baidu’s map api home is http://dev.baidu.com/wiki/map/in...

sogou’s map api home is http://map.sogou.com/api/

actually, in china, as of now, the google maps api are still available now.
as from recent chinatech.us news,
Google China passed the annual inspection and got more opportunity to get online map business license
so, the 3 API are are and available.

Comment: I have read about baidu's map API, and if this demonstration result in a deal we will change to that.

Comment: This is no longer true and has not been for some time now. Google is blocked by the China firewall. You would need to proxy or forward your request to a system outside of China to provide the services of Google APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Beijing, and I can assure you that Google Maps (and all its other services are available).

But what you need to take into consideration, is that traffic from inside China to the outside is far from stable : last week for example, gmail was very unstable, but it all went back to normal after a few days.

Look at China as a giant Enterprise network : sometimes DNS servers go down or the Great mighty firewall goes wrong ...

Also there are periods when the network is more bound to mess up : National holiday (October), Chinese New Year (around February) and last but not least : Communist party elections (in November this year). During these periods, they might decide to temporarily block some websites.

Also, different cities might have different firewall rules : what might work in Beijing, might not work in Shanghai (but this is very rare).

Comment: This is good to hear. This demonstration will take place in a few weeks and as I said I'm locked up with other projects so I don't want to change API if I don't have to.

Comment: I have some bad news for you : http://shanghaiist.com/2012/11/01/beijing_isps_going_down_for_mainten.php  : "Beijing ISPs reportedly going down for 'maintenance' during 18th Party Congress". Personally I don't have any problems since I live in an embassy area, but you might encounter some problems outside. So beware ...