# Is Google Maps Android API v2 available on most android phones in China?

Tags: android, localization, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to develop some android apps using google maps android api 2. But it seems that it is using google play service and most chinese android phones (including knock-off one) don't even have google play. Can I use google maps in my app if the app is going to be deployed in china ?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13174402/996313)

Comment: not exactly the same. I notice google maps android api v2 need some extra service on an android phone, i.e. the google play service. If it is not installed the map is not be available.